# Using PayPal .NET SDK to replace legacy SOAP operations, advice

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

This is more advice on how to go about upgrading to the PayPal .NET SDK.  I've been playing with the SDK using the Nuget package and I'm able to stumble through most of the examples I can find.  The issue is that some of the stuff we are already doing uses features from the other apis like merchant sdk dotnet
which is about to be deprecated.  We are doing everything using the legacy stuff and i'm just not sure what the equivalent of those things are in the new API.

Here's what we are currently doing:

Accept PayPal Payment using Set/Get/Do Express Checkout

Accept credit cards using pay flow pro:

- We get an authorized payment and then store the transaction id.  This allows for saved payments without saving credit card numbers.
- We do a sale payment by passing in a reference transaction id.

As an overview what we are trying to support is the ability to use paypal to checkout without a credit card, or allow the customer to pay with credit cards that can be saved and used again later.  It would also be nice to add the lightbox or mini browser feature so the customer doesn't have to leave our site.

From what i understand so far, and please correct me if i'm wrong, is that to do the express checkout features we should start using the REST create payment function and pass paypal as the payment method. This returns a paymentId and a payerId that i can use later to execute a payment.  I think i'm ok with all of that, but i am confused as to why the token that is returned doesnt work for getting the payment, i have to get a fresh token.  I'm also not sure how to accomplish this inside a lightbox or mini  browser.

I have also figured out how to do a REST payment with credit_card as the payment method, and i see that there is a way to save a payment to their vault.  Am i correct in assuming that the REST api will not support payflow pro and that to accomplish what we were doing before with reference transactions and saved payments we need to move to the vault methods?

Answer (score 0):

I can certainly help you with your **Express Checkout** requirement.

You can leverage [PaySharp.NET](https://github.com/daishisystems/Daishi.PaySharp) in order to provide **Express Checkout** functionality. This SDK encapsulates the REST and HTML-parsing boilerplates necessary to fulfil an **Express Checkout** transaction. It also exposes async functionality.

This library removes the complexities of interfacing with PayPal, and provides PayPal metadata in comprehensible POCOs.